# Members of thread_info struct for linux on x86

Tags: linux

I am going through the Understanding the Linux Kernel book by Bovet and Cesati (3rd Edition, 2005) where they briefly explain that the thread_info structure points to a process descriptor via it's "task" member. However, I was looking for the thread_info struct in the Linux github out of curiousity and it appears that the struct only contains an unsigned long member "flags" (seen here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h). It looks very different from older sources showing the thread_info struct (such as this here: http://hypervsir.blogspot.com/2014/10/in-linux-kernel-threadinfo-is-small-cpu.html). Was thread_info changed recently? Is it used differently than before? Any clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following patch, from about two and a half months ago (September 2016),  removed the "task" member from the thread_info struct:

commit 15f4eae70d365bba26854c90b6002aaabb18c8aa

Author: Andy Lutomirski

Date:   Tue Sep 13 14:29:25 2016 -0700

x86: Move thread_info into task_struct

See:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=15f4eae70d365bba26854c90b6002aaabb18c8aa

Please refer to the following line in this patch:

...

-struct thread_info 
...

...

...